# Warranty for power adapter and earpod

Tags: warranty, iphone

I recently bought an iPhone 6s and given 1 year warranty by Apple. Does the warranty covers other items as well? i.e. the power adapter and the earphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's Service FAQ](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=servicefaq&geo=United_States&product=iphone):

> Apple accessories (including the power adapter and Apple iPhone cases) are also covered by Apple's One Year Limited Warranty. Online service might not be available through Apple for all accessories. Contact your carrier, Apple, or an Apple Authorized Service Provider for details.
>   Read [Apple’s One Year Limited Warranty for iPhone Accessories](https://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/)

Warranty coverage may vary depending on the country you are in, so please verify this for your country.